# RSS Feeds 1 second or less updating

Tags: c#, vb.net, rss

I have a ton of RSS feeds that I need to update every second or less. Is there any solution to everything being bogged down such as partially checking or changes or checking file size or modifying the RSS feed to only show the last news article to reduce bandwidth? This question is really generic to it's solution but specific to RSS feeds so please feel free to add another tag I may have missed.

Comment: Do you provide and control the source for these rss-feeds? A third party might block you if you are trying to request data on this scale.

Comment: @Stefan even if it had to be done every 5 seconds to avoid blockage that would be tolerable but the sheer amount of RSS feeds make this impossible due to the time to load and process them all at once.

Comment: How many feeds are we talking about? And what is your server configuration? What is your bandwidth available? And is your solution scale-able?

Comment: @Stefan 250 feeds to start and easily over 1,000 if we can get it fast enough. I can use an aggregate service for some of the RSS feeds (to combine them) but I like to separate the feeds for organization reasons and not sure if that actually reduces bandwidth and who knows what kind of delay that is introducing.

Comment: Do you have knowledge about multi-threading?

Comment: @Stefan what do you think of RSSOWL I think it would just make sense to modify that for what we are doing.

Comment: I don't have experience with RSSOWL

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but to long for a comment.

**Bandwidth**

Lets do some calculations: a typical rss feed can be somewhere around 200kB (images excluded). Polling a 1000 every second will require a bandwidth of 200MB/s. This would be do-able with a professional internet connection. You would require multiple connections at once though, so you need a multi-threading setup. This setup will eventually make it easier to scale it up over multiple servers if processing time takes to much CPU power.

Be aware, this is without images.

Take a look  at these specifications and be aware of things like `skiphours` and `ttl`. The provide hints about polling the service.

https://cyber.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html

**Processing**

Rss-items typically have a `pubDate`, you can use this to exclude items in  your processing flow. This shouldn't be a bottle-neck. If you save data to a database you might need to dive into that to optimize it.

**Potential problems**

- Blocking due to excessive calls
- Advertisments within the feeds (especially if they use the request date/time in the `pubDate` (I know cnn tends to do this).

Comment: Is there any specific examples or general tip for excessive calls. Like every 5 seconds or every hour or over 500 times in a day? Curious if we know any popular sites that do this and what the limits would be to avoid hitting them.

Comment: It totally depends on the owner of the feed. I know this doesn't help you and the usage-limitations are seldom easy accessible. But if we take a look at instagram (I know, not an RSS feed), you'll find an example: https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/